# Using https with Laravel throws apache error

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I’m trying to make sure all of the routes used within my Laravel project use `https`.

I tried doing this by adding a redirect in my `App::before()` filter in the `filter.php file like so:

```
if (!Request::secure()){
    return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
}
```

This definitely rewrites my urls to use `https` instead of `http`, but the page comes back with an Apache error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) Server at beta.mysite.com Port 443

Is there something else I need to change to allow laravel to see https requests?

**EDIT:** Here’s my current `.htaccess` file’s contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://beta.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yeah, my cert is pointing to `DocumentRoot /var/www/public` which is the document root for non http access.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. My 443 port is definitely set up the same as my non-https port. I should add when I go to the index.php page it loads, but when I try to access any other route in laravel I get the above error.

Comment: I'll update my post with the .htaccess file contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I was running into was actually missing configuration items in the virtualhost for the https site.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                       

                DocumentRoot /var/www/public


                # The section I was missing START
                <Directory />                                                                                         
                        Options FollowSymLinks                                                                        
                        AllowOverride None                                                                            
                </Directory>                                                                                          

                <Directory /var/www/>                                                                                 
                        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                                                    
                        AllowOverride All                                                                             
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
                </Directory>
                # The section I was missing End


...
```

These rules are identical to those found in the virtual host for http (port 80). Without these in place laravel was not able to grab the correct routes.

Once I put these in place for port 443, the regular urls would work with https, e.g. `http://beta.mysite.com/register` and `https://beta.mysite.com/register` would route to the same place.

With this, the default .htaccess file and the secure route redirect work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lead me in the right direction. I used a shorter version though which worked: <Directory "/path/to/public/dir">
 AllowOverride all
</Directory>

Comment: @SabrinaGelbart you just saved my life

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<Directory "/path/to/public/dir"> AllowOverride all </Directory>
```

(Moved from my initial comment so it's easier to find)